# How to use next.config.js redirects to all routes that match a pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js

**Given the business definitions:**

- There are people with names (name + surname) written in PascalCase, such as "JohnDoe" and "AnalyseKitting"
- There are pages such as "home", "profile", "about", "faq" ...

**Given the business needs:**

- When user inputs "www.ourpage.com/JohnDoe" it redirects to "www.ourpage.com/profile/JohnDoe"
- when user inputs "www.ourpage.com/home" there is no redirection

### What I expect

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:personName((?:[A-Z][a-z]+){2})",
        destination: "/profile/:personName",
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
```

this code should match PascalCase only, and redirect to `/profile/:personName` only when there is a positive match.

It does not work, as when writing `/about` it's redirected to `/profile/about`.
here you have an SSCCE sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/redirects-not-working-as-expected-6z909

### What partially works but is not maintainable

to do a negative lookahead of anything that is not from Nextjs or from our list of pages. PascalCase naming is not achieved, though

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:personName((?!_next|about|profile).+)", // not maintainable
        destination: "/profile/:personName",
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
```

Here is a SSCCE working example codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/redirects-working-with-negative-lookahead-bi9xf?file=/next.config.js

### Working workaround but NOT in `redirects()`

It's possible to intercept at server's `getServerSideProps` function by intercepting all requests with a page named `[anyName].js` or `[...anyName].js`, like in the following example

```js
// [...root].js
const personNameRegexp = /^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+){2}$/;
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const isPersonName = personNameRegexp.test(params.root);
  if (isPersonName) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: `profile/${params.root}`,
        permanent: false
      }
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {}
  };
};
```

Here is a SSCCE working example codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/redirections-based-on-regex-cmn6c

### Other workarounds tried without luck

I tried to use the [`has` objects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching) but `personName` is not a query param, apparently, and can't be matched like this:

```js
        has: [
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "personName",
            value: "(?:[A-Z][a-z]+){2}",
          },
        ],
```

#### is there any way to accomplish that in `next.config.js`'s `redirects()` function?

Comment: Hm, the requirements are quite weird, what if the user request `www.ourpage.com/johndoe`?

Comment: Then 404 comes into play

Comment: Well anyway, it looks like this RegExps are case insensitive by default, like the flag `i` is always on. But it's just my guess

Comment: No, @Danila, it's case sensitive. I made an example sandbox in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/redirects-is-case-sensitive-e02kh

Comment: It does not seem to work, there is no redirect at all. What should happen there?

Comment: it ONLY redirects when you click at the button in the home page that directs to "/AbouT", being case sensitive

Comment: redirects "/AbouT" to "profile/AbouT", but not from "/about"

Comment: It does not for me. Nor with clicking, nor with page reload. One thing I also suggest is not to use `permanent: true` while testing, maybe you have some browser cache stored already? Try in incognito mode or with hard reload.

Comment: thanks @Danila now I have something that works, although it's not using `next.config.js`. You were right about browser cache. It fooled me. Redirects is case insensitive in fact